# How to implement a next button click in Java code?

Tags: java, pagination

I am writing code in Java to retrieve and parse source code. The website I am trying to access is:
 http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/SheriffSearch/results.aspx?q=searchType%3dSaleDate%26searchString%3d9%2f30%2f2013%26foreclosureType%3d%27NONT%27%2c+%27PAR%27%2c+%27COMM%27%2c+%27TXLN%27.

The source code is only for the page, even though there are 11 total pages. To access the source code for the next pages, I must click the next button, the reload the page to view the new source code. I need to implement this idea in my code, to have my code retrieve all the different pages of source code.

I have read about possibly using PhantomJS or CasperJS to do this, but I do not know how I would implement those.

My code is as follows:

```
// Scraper class takes an input of a string, and returns the source code of the of the website. Also picks out the needed data
public class Scraper { 

  private static String url; // the input website to be scraped

  public static String sourcetext; //The source code that has been scraped


  //constructor which allows for the input of a URL
  public Scraper(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  //scrapeWebsite runs the method to scrape the input URL and returns a string to be parsed.
  public static void scrapeWebsite() throws IOException {

    URL urlconnect = new URL(url); //creates the url from the variable
    URLConnection connection = urlconnect.openConnection(); // connects to the created URL
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                                                                 connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")); // annonymous class to stream the website
    String inputLine; //creates a new variable of string
    StringBuilder sourcecode = new StringBuilder(); // creates a stringbuilder which contains the sourcecode

    //loop appends to the string builder as long as there is information
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
      sourcecode.append(inputLine);// appends the source code to the sting
    in.close();
    sourcetext = sourcecode.toString(); // Takes the text in stringbuilder and converts it to a string
    sourcetext = sourcetext.replace('"','*'); //deletes the quotes(") so it can be parsed
  }

  //This method parses through the data and adds the necesary information to a specified CSV file
  public static void getPlaintiff() throws IOException {

    PrintWriter docketFile = new PrintWriter("tester.csv", "UTF-8"); // creates the csv file. (name must be changed, override deletes file)

    int i = 0;

    //While loop runs through all the data in the source code. There is (14) entries per page.
    while(i<14) {
      String plaintiffAtty = "PlaintiffAtty_"+i+"*>"; //creates the search string for the plaintiffatty
      Pattern plaintiffPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<="+Pattern.quote(plaintiffAtty)+").*?(?=</span>)");//creates the pattern for the atty
      Matcher plaintiffMatcher = plaintiffPattern.matcher(sourcetext); // looks for a match for the atty

      while (plaintiffMatcher.find()) {
        docketFile.write(plaintiffMatcher.group().toString()+", "); //writes the found atty to the file
      }

      String appraisedValue = "Appraised_"+i+"*>"; //creats the search string for the appraised value
      Pattern appraisedPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<="+Pattern.quote(appraisedValue)+").*?(?=</span>)");//creates the parren for the value
      Matcher appraisedMatcher = appraisedPattern.matcher(sourcetext); //looks for a match to the apreaised value

      while (appraisedMatcher.find()) {
        docketFile.write(appraisedMatcher.group().toString()+"\n"); //writes the found value to the file

      }
      i++;
    }
    docketFile.close(); //closes the file
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered turning the class and method comments into javadoc comments? It will make your code far better that just putting them as line comments before the class/methods.

Comment: You need to figure out what the next button does, what url it calls and what parameters it passes to retrieve that next page. If you can get that information then you are set.

Comment: To Add to ns47731's comment.  I would look into a Firefox plugin called [Live Http Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/).  That program will show you what the next url is that you need to call.  If you MUST do everything progrommatically (even calling the correct javascript function), consider looking into [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) and see how they call javascript and the like.  Best of luck.  Finally, please look into HttpClient to make your HTTP requests.  Using URLConnection is treacherous at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your new, majorly reformatted, restyled, and revamped code; now that it is actually comprehensible, you may be able to solve your own problem. (You might want to revert the try-with-resources part if you are using java 1.6 or earlier, though, because they were only added in 1.7.)

```
/**
 * This class contains methods for is for picking
 * out needed data from the source of a website.
 */
public class Scraper { 

    /**
     * This method scrapes the input URL.
     * @return A string containing the data from the webpage.
     * @throws IOException if there was a problem with accessing the website.
     */
    public static String scrapeWebsite(String url) throws IOException {

        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder sourcetext = new StringBuilder();

        URL urlconnect = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = urlconnect.openConnection();

        try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))){

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                sourcetext.append(inputLine);
        }
        return sourceText.toString().replace('"','*');
    }

    /**
     * This method parses through the data and adds the necesary information to
     * a specified .CSV file.
     * @param source The datasource, for example that returned by
     *               {@link scrapeWebsite()}.
     * @param targetFile The file path for the destination .csv file.
     * @throws IOException if there was a problem with accessing the file.
     */
    public static void getPlaintiff(CharSequence source, String targetFile)
            throws IOException{

        try(PrintWriter docketFile = new PrintWriter("tester.csv", "UTF-8")){

            for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
                Matcher plaintiffMatcher = Pattern.compile(
                        "(?<=PlaintiffAtty_" + i + "\\*>).*?(?=</span>)")
                        .matcher(source);

                while (plaintiffMatcher.find())
                    docketFile.println(plaintiffMatcher.group());

                Matcher appraisedMatcher = Pattern.compile(
                        "(?<=Appraised_" + i + "\\*>).*?(?=</span>)")
                        .matcher(source);

                while (appraisedMatcher.find())
                    docketFile.println(appraisedMatcher.group());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Be aware the potential that new bugs may have been introduced; just fix them, no big deal.)

EDIT: realized that the matcher creation does indeed have to be done inside the loop, because the index is needed to generate the regex; also replaced the `docketWriter.write` with a much simpler `docketWriter.println` statment.